# Concatenate dictionaries using values in different dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, concatenation

I have two dictionaries. Like this:

```
d1 = {A: 1, B:2, C:3}
d2 = {1: xx, 2:xxx, 3:xxxx}
```

I wrote a code to compare both:

```
for k, v in d1.iteritems():
    for l, m in d2.iteritems():
        if l == v:
            print k+'\t'+v+'\t'+m
```

And print as a table like this:

```
A 1 xx
B 2 xxx
C 3 xxxx
```

Suggestions like to create a new_dictionary is accepted.

Comment: I forgot to mention that d2 has more elements than d1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for k, v in d1.iteritems():
    if v in d2:
        print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(k, v, d2[v]))
```

Comment: It gave a conflict because d2 has more elements than d1. And the exceed elements in d2 I don want. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

"Suggestions like to create a new_dictionary is accepted."

```
print {key : [d1[key], d2[d1[key]]] for key in d1 if  d1[key] in d2 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k, v in d1.items():
    print(k, v, d2[v])
```

This is how to do it in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : simple and easy.

```
for i in d1:
    if d1[i] in d2:
        print i,d1[i],d2[d1[i]]
```

Comment: it show me an error. may be because the number of elements in both dictionaries are different.